# How To Use Fusioncharts With Jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

If any one knows, please explain how to use Fusioncharts With Jsf 2.0.
My application contains (.xhtml) pages and is there any specific tag libraries for this ?

Comment: You can adopt the following appraoch, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9886212/617373 , it works with any charts, its an idea... and it tested...

Answer (score 0):

check these plugins, they might be useful to you.

http://aurorarnd.com/website/component/content/article/2-news/44-jsf-plugins.html