# Combining Bar and Line chart in Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Is is possible to combine both the bar and line chart into a single chart?

(where the line chart is over the bar chart)

I'm using Primefaces 3.2, JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 6

Comment: just saying... the original charting library of primefaces (jqPlot) does allow this http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barLineAnimated.html :)

Comment: yup  :)         Actually, I was also looking for JQPlot integration with Prime-faces and didn't find good material on that....

Comment: You can do it yourself , take a look at this answer , its a general approach of working with external charting library http://stackoverflow.com/a/9886212/617373 , but it requires some jquery / json skills

Comment: i dont think its possible with primefaces : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20244   B.T.W keep an eye on http://code.google.com/p/plotfaces/ its not out yet (i don't know if it will ever be...) but it seems that this is the exact library you were looking for (in combination with primefaces)

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the inputs!!  it really helps!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its possible with primefaces : [Combining Bar and Line chart in Primefaces](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20244)

B.T.W keep an eye on [plotfaces](http://code.google.com/p/plotfaces/) its not out yet (I don't know if it will ever be...) but it seems that this is the exact addition library you were looking for... (in combination with primefaces)

**Note this :**

You can always do it yourself , take a look at this answer , its a general approach of working with external charting library [General Approach of working with charts in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879281/jsf-highcharts-and-js/9886212#9886212) , but it requires some jquery / json skills