# Highcharts Java Api wrapper for JSF?

Tags: api, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, highcharts

I am looking [on the official site of Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/download) for Api wrappers and it does not contain an Api wrapper for Java. It only has [highcharts-serverside-export](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export) which is for generating images on server side. Does anybody know if something like [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) exists for JSF? I have come across this question as how to use [Highcharts with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879281/jsf-highcharts-and-js), but surely there must be some Api like that from .NET?

Comment: Could you please be more precise about the usage scenario?
AFAIK know Highcharts is executed completely on the client side. So,  there should be no need to have a server side wrapper. 
However, it is very easy to create custom tags or composite components for convenience reasons. These could utilize the client-side functionality of Highcharts and act as "wrapper" if needed.

Comment: Please look at the DotNet.HighCharts link in my OP for example.

Comment: Could not find any however I am starting an open source project for highstock on github to do exactly this. Have not committed anything as just yet. help welcome: https://github.com/bernalrs/highjsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem as you. I started writing my own custom components to bridge JSF and highcharts. I have made [my code available](http://kevindoran1.blogspot.co.nz/2012/12/using-highcharts-in-jsf.html). It's not a full wrapper, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. After I could not found any wrapper I just wrote it in pure JS. Maybe that is why there is no API, because it really does not take a lot of time to implement highchart library.